# how to find the value of K in quadratic equations

Tags: polynomials

look at the following question

> If one of the Zeros of polynomial $f(x)=Kx^2-17K+(3K-2)$ is reciprocal
>   of other zero, then K is equal to:
>
> (a) 1, (b) -1, (c) 2, (d)-2

i solve the above question as follows

let the one zero be $a$ then,

$a=1/a$ because one zero is reciprocal of another,

then

taking $x=a$,

=>   $k(a)^2-17k+(3k-2)=0$
=>   $a^2k-17k+3k-2=0$
=>  $a^2k-14k-2=0$.....(1)

now taking $x=1/a$

$k(1/a)^2-17k+(3k-2)=0$,
$k/a^2-14k-2=0$,
$k-14ka^2+2a^2/a^2=0$    .....(2)

since equation 1 and 2 are equal to same thing then (1)=(2)

therefore $a^2k-14k-2=k-14ka^2-2a^2/a^2$,
$a^2(a^2k-14k-2)=k-14ka^2-2a^2$, 
$a^4k-14ka^2-2a^2=k-14ka^2-2a^2$,
$a^4k-14ka^2+14ka^2-2a^2+2a^2=k$,
$a^4k=k$,
$a^4=1$,
hence, $a=1$

fortunately the answer is correct but i had found the value of $a$ instead of $k$, then what is the mistake ?

thanks.

Comment: Where did the $a^2/a^2$ come from in (2)? And in (2) why did the term change from - 2 to + 2?

Comment: it is whole upon $a^2$

Comment: Did you multiply both sides by $a^2$ in the last step of (2)?

Comment: yes...that why there is $14ka^2$ in the last step of equation 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one root is reciprocal of another,their product is $1$

So, using Vieta's formula we have $\displaystyle 1=\frac{3K-2}K$

Comment: is root is also called zero of any polynomial ?

Comment: @anni, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_of_a_function

Comment: how to solve this? with this formula

Comment: @anni, We are interested in $K$ only, right?